# Chrome for iOS MSE support

Tags: html, html5, online-video

На странице https://caniuse.com/#feat=mediasource мы можем видеть, что MSE не поддерживается на Safari для iOS, а Chrome имеет поддержку MSE без любых комментариев по данному поводу. Но я вижу что код, который использует MSE (video.js проигрыватель, воспроизведение flv) и хорошо работает для Win/Linux/Mac Desktop Chrome и других браузеров (MS Edge, Firefox) не работает на Chrome для iOS.
Пожалуйста помогите прояснить вопрос о поддержке MSE для Chrome под iOS. Ссылки на документацию приветствуются.

Answer (score 0):

Как то я сразу не заметил, что на https://caniuse.com/#feat=mediasource, если навести мышь на данные для Safari, то появляется всплывающая подсказка, что для Safari и Chrome MSE под iOS не поддерживается.